# Sails JS Installation Error and Advice

Tags: linux, sails.js

I am starting to taste the sweetness of Node and I am thinking of using Sails for a new free service I am trying to create.

But I am having problems installing Sails. I get the following error when it goes to install.

```
npm ERR! error installing sails@0.8.91
npm ERR! error rolling back sails@0.8.91 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails'

npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: forever@0.10.0
npm ERR! Required: {"node":"0.8.x"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/test/ruby
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! message Unsupported
npm ERR! errno {}
```

Is this some sort of compatibility with my Node version. I updated it to latest I guess a couple weeks back. I use NVM.

How can I rectify this and go ahead the installation before the enthusiasm dies :)

One extra advice, I would really appreciate and a thumb up for any good answer/s.

I am looking in to Node to create a free web service. Performance is my utmost concern to reduce cost.

The service is basically pull and show from the database or store. I am good with PHP alright with Rails and Sinatra. I see Sinatra to be light weight. Some where I red that the way node works it could scale better than Sinatra. Am I correct? What would be the best option of all. Btw, I am expecting to host in Hiroku.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Not compatible with your version of node/npm` in the error message is pretty self explanatory. You need to upgrade node.js to a newer version.

Comment: my default node version is -> `0.10.5 (-> v0.10.5)`

Comment: Do I need to downgrade it to 0.8 ?

Comment: Then why is it finding 0.6.12?

Comment: Thats what I have been looking in to. I am using NVM and under sudo it s not finding its installation path. The reason why I use NVM is because Ubuntu repos give very old versions.